# Dc search box plugin is not working in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I installed Dc search plugin . I apply this plugin on deal page it works properly.
 But on contact index page it not working. difference on both page are contact page contains the relation of multiple tables like company, company_contacts,units,taxes and many more. but in deal page data comes only from the deals table. feside this there is no difference on both. And second one is as model for contact index page i use the company.php instead of contact.php.

In My index.php

```
        <?php if(!empty($search_args['search_cname'])): ?>
        <strong><?php echo __('Company Name:'); ?> </strong><span><?php echo $search_args['search_cname']; ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(!empty($search_args['search_name'])): ?>
        <strong><?php echo __('Contact Person:'); ?> </strong><span><?php echo $search_args['search_name']; ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(!empty($search_args['search_status'])): ?>
        <strong><?php echo __('Status:'); ?> </strong><span><?php echo $search_args['search_status']; ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(!empty($search_args['search_uname'])): ?>
        <strong><?php echo __('User Name:'); ?> </strong><span><?php echo $search_args['search_uname']; ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="filter-box" style="display:none">
        <?php echo $this->Form->create('company', array('url' => array_merge(array('controller'=>'contacts','action' => 'index'), $this->params['pass']),'class'=>'form-inline')); ?>
        <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __(Filters); ?></legend>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('search_status',array('div'=>false,'class'=>'span2','options'=>array(4=>'Lead',5=>'Opportunity',6=>'Account'),'label'=>'Status ',)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('search_cname',array('div'=>false,'class'=>'span2','label'=>'Company Name ','placeholder'=>'Company Name')); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('search_name',array('div'=>false,'class'=>'span2','label'=>'Contact Person ','placeholder'=>'Contact Person')); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('search_uname',array('div'=>false,'class'=>'span2','label'=>'User Name ','placeholder'=>'User Name')); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Filter',array('div'=>false,'class'=>'btn btn-info')); ?>
        </fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
```

In ContactController.php

```
 $searched = false;
if ($this->passedArgs) {
        $args = $this->passedArgs;
        if(isset($args['search_cname'])){
            $searched = true;
        }
        if(isset($args['search_name'])){
            $searched = true;
        }
    }
    $this->set('searched',$searched);
```

In Model contact.php

```
  public $actsAs = array(
        'Search.Searchable',
        );

            public $filterArgs = array(
                    'search_status' => array('type'=>'value','field'=>'company.contact_status_id'),
                    'search_cname' => array('type'=>'like','field'=>array('company.company_name')),
                    'search_name' => array('type'=>'like','field'=>array('company_contacts.first_name','company_contacts.last_name')),
                    'search_uname' => array('type'=>'like','field'=>'User.full_name'),

        'search_all' => array('type'=>'query','method'=>'searchDefault')
);

public function searchDefault($data = array()) {
    $filter = $data['search_all'];
    $cond = array(
            'OR' => array(
               // 'company.company_name LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
                'company_contacts.first_name LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',

                'company_contacts.last_name LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',

                 'company_contacts.email LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
                 'company_contacts.mobile_number LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',

                    $this->alias . '.company_name LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
                        'User.full_name LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
                //  $this->alias . '.first_name LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
                //  $this->alias . '.last_name LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
            //      $this->alias . '.status LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%'
            ));
    return $cond;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Include the Prg component in your controller as below

```
public $components = array("Search.Prg");
```

Then in your action add the following line at top

```
$this->Prg->commonProcess();

$this->Paginator->settings['conditions'] = $this->Contact->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs);
$this->set('searched', $this->Paginator->paginate());
```

For more details, Please have a look [here](https://github.com/CakeDC/search/blob/master/Docs/Tutorials/Quick-Start.md)

Comment: I try this. but unfortunately it gives the following error                                                                  Error: Call to undefined method PrgComponent::parsedParams()
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\salescrm\app\Controller\ContactsController.php
Line: 51

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\fatal_error.ctp

Comment: Ok, Got you point
Please replace $this->Prg->parsedParams() with $this->passedArgs and try again. Lemme know if still not working

Comment: @PriyankaSingh I have edited the answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this, my own custom

Add the following line in controller

```
public $presetVars = array();
```

then

```
public function index() {
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $this->Contact->data["Contact"] = $this->passedArgs;
    $this->request->data["Contact"] = $this->passedArgs;
    $parsedConditions[] = $this->filter_condition($this->passedArgs);

    $this->paginate = array(
        "conditions" => $parsedConditions
    );
    $this->set('result', $this->paginate());
}

public function filter_condition($data = array()) {
    $parsedConditions = array();
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $data = array_map('trim', $data);
        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                foreach ($this-> Contact->filterArgs as $k => $v) {
                    if ($key == $v["name"]) {
                        $value = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $value);
                        $value = Sanitize::clean($value);
                        if ($value != null) {
                            if ($v["type"] == "string") {
                                $parsedConditions[] = array("Contact.$key LIKE" => "%" . $value . "%");
                            } else if ($v["type"] == "value") {
                                $parsedConditions[] = array("Contact.$key" => $value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $parsedConditions;
}
```

And in the model do write filter args like this

/* Filter fileds to search */

```
public $filterArgs = array(
        array("name" => "field1", "type" => "value"),
        array("name" => "field2", "type" => "string")
 );
```